# Configuring PHP in IIS with Tomcat

Tags: java, php, iis, tomcat, fastcgi

I have my Java site running under IIS 7. I need to install wordpress blog in it. I've installed and configured PHP in IIS. I have tested the PHP handler by creating a separate site, everything works fine, phpinfo() gives the desired output.

However, I'm having problem running the PHP files inside my Java web application. I've put my test PHP file inside a folder called blog. When I access this folder in the browser as /mysite/blog I get a 404 page from my Java application. When I try to invoke the php page directly, http://mysite/blog/index.php, I get an unprocessed php page.

I'm using isapi_handler for the reidrects. How do I tell my isapi_handler to ignore /blog folder? In my IIS handler mapping, *.php is mapped with Fast CGI. I'm not sure how to approach this problem and any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I now declare you Web App Server king.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the blog directory from uriworkermap.properties seems to solve my problem. Here is the line I added to uriworkermap.properties -

!/mysite/blog/*=tomcat

This tells the isapi_redirect to ignore /blog folder.